# getActivity gives null from setUserVisibleHint() in Android N (support-v4:24.1.0)

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment, android-support-library, android-7.0-nougat

I am working on ViewPager and using setUserVisibleHint() in my Fragment class. And, I am invoking getActivity() inside setUserVisibleHint().

Prior to Android N, It is working fine. But, In Android N getActivity() is giving NullPointerException.

As per the v4-support library(Revision 24.1.0) documentation, they have already fixed the issue. But it's still not working for me though I am using the same.

Below is the code snippet

```
@Override
  public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) {
    super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser);

    if (isVisibleToUser && getXYZ(getActivity())) { //getActivity() gives null pointer exception

    }
  }
```

Comment: Use `25.0.0` which is the latest. Also, show code.

Comment: I am also facing the same issue.

Comment: As per my project requirement I can't use 25.0.0. Please suggest if I can achieve it using 24.x.x. Updated the question with code snippet

Comment: @JaredBurrows, I have tried with 25.0.0. Still it's crashing. Thanks!

Comment: What is `getXYZ`? Show us more code.

Comment: @Jared Burrows! In my Case, I'm trying to access the **SharedPreferences** by passing context using **getActivity()** to method. Here, **getActivity()** is giving **NPE**.